# How to stub the Params values when i am testing a controller by Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, parameters, specifications

Can anyone please let me know if it is possible to stub params[] values in controller spec, so that the controller accepts the stubbed values as actual params[] value from view.

for example,
my view has a statement as

```
<%= form_tag("/expense_details/add_expense", :method=>"post") do %>
<%= text_field_tag(:eamt, nil, placeholder: "Expense Amount") %>
```

my controller has a statement as

```
expense_type= params[ :eamt ]
if !expense_type.nil?
session[:emsg]="filled"
else
session[:emsg]="empty"
end
```

my controller spec is as follows

```
it "successful save" do
my spec has condition as
post 'add_expense' 
session[:emsg].should == "filled"
end
```

But my test is faling everytime with this below status

```
 Failure/Error: session[:emsg].should == "filled"
   expected: "filled"
        got: "empty" (using ==)
```

can anyone please let me know how can i achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In the RSpec controller spec, change the post line to:

```
post 'add_expense', eamt: 'stubbed_value'
```

The `post` method accepts a hash of options that will be considered parameters to the request. [Docs from Rspec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-4/docs/request-specs/request-spec)